# Trying to remove unknown and specific characters once from a string

Tags: java, string, replace, character

I have a command line argument that looks like this:
`"111234++"`. It is not hard-coded, so it could vary. Just for the sake of example, I'll stick to that specific input though.
Then there is going to be another expression, like this one: "11+". My ultimate goal is the removal of these occurrences from the input string. This means, the following string: "111234++" should get converted into this the smaller one right here: "1234+". For some reason I can't get this to work. Here is what I tried:

```
if (isExpressionInInventory(expression, inventoryPlayer1)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char character  = expression.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < inventoryPlayer1.length(); j++) {
            if (inventoryPlayer1.charAt(j) == character) {
                inventoryPlayer1 = inventoryPlayer1.replace(character, ' ');
                expression = expression.replace(character, ' ');
            }
        }
    }
    inventoryPlayer1 = inventoryPlayer1.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

---

I tried iterating over the string-expression and store the character consecutively. My first character should be "1" then.. The nested for loop iterates through the inventory "111234++" and replaces each occurrence of the character with an empty character. This is the moment where my program has its flaw. I only want to replace one occurrence of that character. Sadly, I have no idea how to tackle this issue..
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `expression = expression.replace(character, ' ');` will replace *all* `character` occurances. So `"11+".replace('1',' ')` will become `"  +"`. To replace *first* occurrence of that character you may want to use `replaceFirst`. Since it uses regex, you want to generate regex which represents that character (in case such character is regex metacharacter like `+`). To do that you can use `Pattern.quote` but it expects String. So you also need to convert your `character` to String first. Final version could look like `expression = expression.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(""+character), "");`.

Comment: Same for player inventory. BTW replacing character with `""` (empty string) instead of `' '` (space) also lets you avoid `inventoryPlayer1 = inventoryPlayer1.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` since you are not adding any spaces now.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how to implement this still. But I will try to figure it out. Just replacing this "expression = expression.replaceFirst..." doesn't work. So I'll just see how you meant it and hopefully I'll get it. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. BTW if instead of String you can use other structures like List then you could use `yourList.remove(element)` which would remove *first* occurrence of that element from your list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to remove any repeated characters.

The following regular expression pattern will match any character that is immediately followed by the same character.

```
(.)\1
```

You can use this within a `String.replaceAll` method.

```java
String string = "111234++"
while (string.matches(".*(.)\\1.*"))
    string = string.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1");
```

The `string.matches` call is asserting that `string` contains at least 1 repeated set.
And, the `string.replaceAll` call is replacing the double-occurrence with a single occurrence.